# Crawler with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I am trying to create a web crawler for student research. I have already finish it, but I would like to tell me if the way I use is the best one. (probably it isn't :p)

The crawler is for the cnn site and the only thing I want to get, is the text of the news.

Here is an example link: [link](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/08/21/world/asia/japan-nuclear-leak-warning/index.html)

Here is my code:

```
def cnn_crawler(link):
    req = urllib2.Request(link, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    encoding = usock.headers.getparam('charset')
    page = usock.read().decode(encoding)
    usock.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'cnn_strycntntlft'})
    text = div.find_all('p')
    text.remove(soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'cnn_strycbftrtxt'}))
    final = ""
    for entry in text:
            final = final + entry.get_text() + " "
    return final
```

Answer (score 2):

The code looks good! A few comments:

- I'd use the requests library instead of urrllib2.
- Make sure to follow PEP8 (second line has a trailing whitespace and a space after the dictionary key).
- Use more semantic variable names than `div`, `text`, or `final`.
- If your code gets bigger, think about separating the HTTP request from the parsing code.